# Summary in R for frequency tables?

Tags: r, frequency-analysis

I have a set of user recommandations

```
review=matrix(c(5:1,10,2,1,1,2), nrow=5, ncol=2, dimnames=list(NULL,c("Star","Votes")))
```

and wanted to use `summary(review)` to show basic properties *mean, median, quartiles and min max*.

But it gives back the summary of both columns. I refrain from using `data.frame` because the factors 'Star' are ordered.
**How can I tell R that Star is a <strike>ordered list of factors</strike> numeric score and votes are their frequency?**

Comment: I just saw the tag frequency-analysis. Are you looking for table()? Or contingency tables?

Comment: i tried table didn't work. I somhow need to do mean, median, quartiles. and i dont want to do it by hand. thats a minimum I expect from a statistical framework

Comment: Note that the weighted mean of an _ordered factor_ is not defined, because the whole point of not calling it numeric is that the between-level intervals are not known. You have to assign numeric scores to take means.

Comment: Thanks Aniko, I understand your argument. To name the beast. I want to do it with Amazon reviews. I think they see ratings as cardinal since they do compute the mean

Comment: What you are really looking for is the mean, and quantiles of the Stars *weighted* by the Votes. And Al3xa's approach is a good way to get this. There is really no need to make the Star column a factor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by taking the mean in general if Star is supposed to be an ordered factor.  However, in the example you give where Star is actually a set of numeric values, you can use the following:

```
library(Hmisc)

R> review=matrix(c(5:1,10,2,1,1,2), nrow=5, ncol=2, dimnames=list(NULL,c("Star","Votes")))

R> wtd.mean(review[, 1], weights = review[, 2])
[1] 4.0625

R> wtd.quantile(review[, 1], weights = review[, 2])
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
1.00 3.75 5.00 5.00 5.00
```

Comment: I really like this approach better than al3xa's because i don't need to "decompress" the scores with their weights. But its a shame that is not in the base package. this certainly is daily bread for statistics

Comment: Use `weighted.mean` in base R.

Comment: thats great, i would give you the "right answer" if its was not a comment

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what's the problem. Why shouldn't you use `data.frame`?

```
rv <- data.frame(star = ordered(review[, 1]), votes = review[, 2])
```

You should convert your `data.frame` to vector:

```
( vts <- with(rv, rep(star, votes)) )
 [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 3 2 1 1
Levels: 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5
```

Then do the summary... I just don't know what kind of summary, since `summary` will bring you back to the start. O_o

```
summary(vts)
 1  2  3  4  5 
 2  1  1  2 10
```

**EDIT** *(on @Prasad's suggestion)*

Since `vts` is an ordered factor, you should convert it to numeric, hence calculate the summary (at this moment I will disregard the background statistical issues):

```
nvts <- as.numeric(levels(vts)[vts])  ## numeric conversion
summary(nvts)  ## "ordinary" summary
fivenum(nvts)  ## Tukey's five number summary
```

Comment: I want to see mean, median, quartiles and min/max, this is what I mean by summary

Comment: `summary(as.numeric(vts))` or even better `summary(as.numeric(levels(vts)[vts]))`. The latter approach is recommended.

Comment: +1 I would recommend putting this in the main answer just to make it clear.

Comment: Damn, my mental registry betrayed me this time... I'll try to recall where did I read about this one. Good question, though. =)

Comment: Conversion to vector is not possible if frequencies are huge!

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify -- when you say you would like "mean, median, quartiles and min/max", you're talking in terms of number of stars? e.g mean = 4.062 stars?
Then using aL3xa's code, would something like `summary(as.numeric(as.character(vts)))` be what you want?